# JavaScript new Date() comparison

Tags: javascript

Here my code,

```
var date1 = joiningDate.split('-');
  var tempjoiningDate = date1[1] + '-' + date1[0] + '-' + date1[2];
  var date2 = birthdayDate.split('-');
  var tempbirthdayDate = date2[1] + '-' + date2[0] + '-' + date2[2];
  var jd = new Date(date1[0], date1[1] - 1, date1[2]);
  var bd = new Date(date2[0], date2[1] - 1, date2[2]);
  if (jd <= bd) {
  console.log("correct dates");
  }
  else {
  console.log("Incorrect dates");
  }
```

In this joining date and birthdayDate are in d-m-y format. So i changed to y-m-d format using split and compare these two dates. But it is not working as i expected.

Is anything wrong in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script nearly works. Date() expects the parameters as Integers. So you should cast the strings with leading zeros, using parseInt.

Further more: Are you sure, that Joindate should be earlier than Birthdate??

```js
var joiningDate = '2018-03-08';
var birthdayDate = '1960-01-01';

  var date1 = joiningDate.split('-');
  var date2 = birthdayDate.split('-');
  var jd = new Date(parseInt(date1[0]), parseInt(date1[1]) - 1, parseInt(date1[2]));
  var bd = new Date(parseInt(date2[0]), parseInt(date2[1]) - 1, parseInt(date2[2]));
 
  if (jd <= bd) {
    console.log("Join Date is earlier");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Birth Date is earlier");
  }
```

But you could also directly pass the date strings to the Date object:

```
var jd = new Date(joiningDate);
```

See here for an explanation of the Date Object:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: It compares only the date not month and year.

Comment: I tried for 05-02-2018 as joining date and 08-01-2016 as birth date, when console it, it shows: Join Date is earlier

Comment: You are right - you cannot pass any format to Date(). It must be YYYY-MM-DD. Or you use your function - but then you need to change the indexes of date1 and date2.

Comment: Which format do you use? Is 05-02-2018 in February or in May?

Comment: Thanks @Gerfried.

Answer (score 0):

Set the time part to `0`

```
jd.setHours( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
bd.setHours( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
```

Change the condition to

```
if (jd.getTime() <= bd.getTime()) {
```

**Edit**

Original comparison should work as is

```
if (jd <= bd) {
```

**Demo**

```js
var joiningDate = "05-02-2018";
var birthDate = "08-01-2016";

var fnToDate = str => { 
  var items = str.split( "-" );
  var date = new Date( items[2], items[1] - 1, items[0] );
  date.setHours( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
  return date;
};

console.log( fnToDate( joiningDate ) );
console.log( fnToDate( birthDate ) );
console.log( fnToDate( joiningDate ) < fnToDate( birthDate ) );
```

Comment: it also compares the date only not month and year.

Comment: No, it will compare the entire date.

Comment: I tried for 05-02-2018 as joining date and 08-01-2016 as birth date, when console it, it shows: Join Date is earlier

Comment: OK, let me share a demo

Comment: Okay. waiting for that.

Comment: @Newbie007 Check the demo.